# Replace min by a quantile in a transform after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am calculating the minimum of each group using this piece of code:

```
df['columnname'].groupby(group_identifier).transform('min')
```

This works well but I now want to calculate the 10% quantile of each group instead of the minimum. How do I modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `"quantile"` instead of `"min"` and also pass the quantile cut point as `q`:

```
df[column_name].groupby(group_identifier).transform("quantile", q=0.1)
```